# why are folder names green in color ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ls

I have folders in green color when I do ls -l then they appear colored
[you can see in the link folders are all green in color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7vz.png)
what could be reason for this.

Comment: Do this if you don't want colors (or if you want to understand why your ls is colored). Open /home/<user-name>/.bashrc file and look for the variable:
force_color_prompt=yes. If it is linke in my copy/paste (uncommented), try to comment it: #force_color_prompt=yes
and then execute from terminal: source /home/<user-name>/.bashrc

Comment: specifically (from the linked duplicate) *"Blue with green background: other-writable directory"*